# Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I did an application in VS2015 and Crystal Report, I can run it in the development machine (32bits) with no problem, I can load the forms where is CrystalReportViewer and print, all works fine but when I install it in another PC (32bits) and I try to load the form that have the CrystalReportViewer I get: "System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0 , Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies"

This is all I did:

I confirmed that log4net.dll exist in my debug folder

I saw the version (1.2.13.0) and change it for 1.2.10.0

I tested with a lot of configurations in app.config

I tried this official wiki: 
https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Using+Crystal+Reports+for+Visual+Studio+2010+Merge+Modules+(MSM)+to+create+a+Setup+project
(I can´t find any CRRuntime_13_x.msm file)

But the error still showing up

Please can you help me?

Comment: trace the fusion data with ETW/xperf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net/29374658#29374658 Also open the ETL in WPA.exe (part of Windows Perf Toolkit) look at the Image-Graph and look at the load stack of log4net to see more details.

Comment: Thanks magic, but I just fixed installing CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_16.msi which is not a nice solution but it worked for me because I was hurry

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick solution installing CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_16.msi in the new PC, it is not a good solution and I must say that from now I prefer to do the reports with VB Net entirely.